# How can I store multiple values in a Perl hash table?

Tags: perl, hash, multiple-value, perl-data-structures

Up until recently, I've been storing multiple values into different hashes with the same keys as follows:

```
%boss = (
    "Allan"  => "George",
    "Bob"    => "George",
    "George" => "lisa" );

%status = (
    "Allan"  => "Contractor",
    "Bob"    => "Part-time",
    "George" => "Full-time" );
```

and then I can reference `$boss("Bob")` and `$status("Bob")` but this gets unwieldy if there's a lot of properties each key can have and I have to worry about keeping the hashes in sync.

Is there a better way for storing multiple values in a hash?  I could store the values as

```
        "Bob" => "George:Part-time"
```

and then disassemble the strings with split, but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: This is a great reminder of why the Perl Data structure cookbook is such a great resource.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is the standard way, as per [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

```
~> more test.pl
%chums = ( "Allan" => {"Boss" => "George", "Status" => "Contractor"},
           "Bob" => {"Boss" => "Peter", "Status" => "Part-time"} );

print $chums{"Allan"}{"Boss"}."\n";
print $chums{"Bob"}{"Boss"}."\n";
print $chums{"Bob"}{"Status"}."\n";
$chums{"Bob"}{"Wife"} = "Pam";
print $chums{"Bob"}{"Wife"}."\n";

~> perl test.pl
George
Peter
Part-time
Pam
```

Comment: That looks okay.  I guess I can add another chum with $chums{"Greg"} = {"Boss" => "Lisa", "Status" => "Fired"} but how do I go about adding a wife to Bob?  Would that be $chums{"Bob"}{"Wife"} = "Carol"?

Comment: Also, why the "->".  It seems to function without these.

Comment: TIMTOWDI :), you can use it without them, and yes, your way to add a wife is correct

Comment: This is a great reminder of the value of the perldsc.

This should be required reading for PHP, Python, Ruby and Perl programmers.

Answer (score 23):

Hashes of hashes is what you're explicitly asking for. There is a tutorial style piece of documentation part of the Perl documentation which covers this: [Data Structure Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) But maybe you should consider going object-oriented. This is sort of the stereotypical example for object oriented programming tutorials.

How about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Employee;
use Moose;
has 'name' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' );

# should really use a Status class
has 'status' => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' );

has 'superior' => (
  is      => 'rw',
  isa     => 'Employee',
  default => undef,
);

###############
package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

my %employees; # maybe use a class for this, too

$employees{George} = Employee->new(
  name   => 'George',
  status => 'Boss',
);

$employees{Allan} = Employee->new(
  name     => 'Allan',
  status   => 'Contractor',
  superior => $employees{George},
);

print $employees{Allan}->superior->name, "\n";
```

Comment: This has the benefit that it can be enhanced in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Hashes can contain other hashes or arrays. If you want to refer to your properties by name, store them as a hash per key, otherwise store them as an array per key.

There is a [reference for the syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
my %employees = (
    "Allan" => { "Boss" => "George", "Status" => "Contractor" },
);

print $employees{"Allan"}{"Boss"}, "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

%chums = ( "Allan" => {"Boss" => "George", "Status" => "Contractor"},
           "Bob" => {"Boss" => "Peter", "Status" => "Part-time"} );

works great but is there a faster way to enter the data?

I am thinking of something like

%chums = (qw, x)( Allan Boss George Status Contractor Bob Boss Peter Status Part-time)

where x = the number of secondary keys after the primary key, in this case x = 2, "Boss" and "Status"