# three item HashMap without internal iteration

Tags: data-structures, collections, hashtable, hashmap

What is the best way to implement a three item hashMap?
For example, I would like to use a regular String key , but have it map to two different objects. The idea is like having a list of lists, except that the first item is a key.

I am trying to avoid iterating through the list ( so the behavior is like a hashmap ). Would you agree the only way is to build a new Class? It seems a "HashMap3" object ( with methods of get1( key ) & get2( key ) ) would be useful. I am unsure of how to set this up myself.

How can I create the collection?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What are these three items?

Comment: What do you mean? A hashmap that stores 3 entries?  Or a key1 => key2 => value hashmap?

Comment: Do you mean a hashmap with a composite key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the key will always map to *exactly* two Objects, then the easiest way to do this is to make a `Pair` class that exists only to hold the two objects.  Then you use your String as the key and the `Pair` instance as the value.  However, if the key can map to arbitrarily many Objects, then IMO the best way to do this is to have the value stored in the `Map` be a `Collection` of some sort.

Comment: I do not think this would be simpler than building a "collection" object that handles more than one value. It seems a "HashMap3" object ( with methods of get1( key ) & get2( key ) ) would be useful. I am unsure of how to set this up myself.

Comment: It would be *way* simpler than building your own Collection object. The Collection interface is large and there are many optional methods. A Pair object is trivial.  Yes, *usage* of a new collection (HashMap2 to indicate two values for one key) and *usage* of a Pair class are about the same.  But creating the Pair object is trivial and creating a new Collection class is complicated, especially if you want it to be Thread safe and if you implement *all* optional methods.

Comment: As I seem not to be able to come up with one on my own , I am forced to agree. I think a hashMap ( key , ArrayList ) will work simply enough , still be expandable , and not need iterated if the insertion is consistently ordered. 

This is simpler than trudging through a new Collections creation. 
Thank you for your time , Eddie.

Answer (score 0):

Look at google-collections [Multimap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

> A collection similar to a Map, but
>   which may associate multiple values
>   with a single key. If you call put(K,
>   V) twice, with the same key but
>   different values, the multimap
>   contains mappings from the key to both
>   values.

Comment: The Google Multimap appears to return a Collection , which still has to be iterated... Was it you that mentioned the Apache Flat3Map? I am wondering why that suggestion was removed.

Comment: I did post about Flat3Map but then realized that you want 2 values for 1 key.  Flat3Map is about fast access for small (size<=3) hashmaps (1 key to 1 value).

Answer (score 0):

A [hash of hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190450/how-can-i-store-multiple-values-in-a-perl-hash-table/190497#190497) perhaps?

Comment: Maybe a hash of a List objects. It seems the simplest solution , and I will not have to iterate if the order is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eddie, and just had a similar problem only with many values, not two. I wanted a Java ConcurrentHashMap to hold a cache XML of documents being fetched from a web service, and I needed to record various pieces of information alongside the XML to support the cache's eviction strategies (eg, Least Recently Used, Least Frequently Used).

The solution was just to define a class of object that holds those items.  I used a private nested class inside of my Cache class, something like this:

```
private static class CacheEntry
{
    private String  uri;          // Key
    private String  fetched_xml;  // The XML document (main value)
    private long    put_time;
    private long    expires_time;
    private long    size;
    private long    hits;
    private long    last_used_time;
}
```

The ConcurrentHashMap was keyed on the URI and looked like this:

```
private final Map<String, CacheEntry> cache;
    [...]
cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, CacheEntry>(100, 0.75f, 3);
```

This code adds a new XML document to the cache:

```
CacheEntry value = new CacheEntry();
value.fetched_xml(fetched_xml); 
value.uri = uri;
value.put_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
value.expires_time = representation.getExpirationDate().getTime();
value.size = bytes_fetched;
value.hits = 0;
value.last_used_time = 0;
cache.put(uri, value);
```

**Edit:** Should you need to Map a key to a *List* of n Objects in Java, you can put those objects in a java.util.collections.ArrayList and use the ArrayList as the Map value.

Comment: Thank you , Jim , for a specific solution example.